# Error file is not defined in React (won't export)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Keep getting an error while following a tutorial:

> `src/components/MyApp.js`   Line 17:18:  'myApp' is not defined
> no-undef Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

This is my `myApp.js`:

```
import React from 'react'

function MyApp() {
    return  (
      <div>
      <h1>hello world</h1>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }

  export default myApp
```

and this is my `index.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import MyApp from './components/MyApp.js';

ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

It'll work perfectly fine in a function, but if I try to take it out and place it into a new folder it won't read it.

Thank you. This is how the file looks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It was a typo Error. (in `export default`).

```
import React from 'react'

function MyApp() {
    return  (
      <div>
      <h1>hello world</h1>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }

  export default MyApp
```

Comment: hm i still get the same error and the tutorial doesn't have a semicolon.. could it be something else? Or maybe I didn't save the file properly (new to VS)

Comment: I don't see any other issue. It is the same error, `myApp is not defined...`, right? Maybe you didn't save the file properly. Press Ctrl+S to save the file. Also try re-running the project.

Comment: yeah its really weird, same error: ```src/MyApp.js
  Line 24:18:  'myApp' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run everything by deleting everything and starting over. I feel as though there might've been a react file misplaced somewhere and it just could not read MyApp.js.